# build error 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly '

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I'm amateur in c#, I learned basics and start programming, I try to download open source projects from svn of sf.net but in compile of most of them I faced with an error like this:

```
build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly '
```

and in continue of error it give a publicKeyToken and no line give me.
What is wrong? I just open project with Visual studio .net 2010 and try to debug. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have some assembly reference which may not exists or may have wrong details.
You need to either correct the details in the web.config or you need to install assembly reference to your c drive

Comment: It's Windows program, How I can find what assembly reference I need?

Answer (score -1):

> Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' because it has not been preloaded.
>   When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on >demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

To resolve it you can just switch off in VisualStudio: Debug->Exceptions->System.IO

Comment: This does not turn of the exception, it simples makes the debugger ignore the exception. You program will still crash (or throw the exception).